# does time complexity changes according to language?

Tags: time-complexity

I already read [Does time complexity changes as we change our programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53919758/does-time-complexity-changes-as-we-change-our-programming-language)

but my question is if time complexity doesn't change according to language then which is the base language on which we should calculate time complexity. is it C/C++ or any other?

To get element in array in java I use `.contains` method. so does that mean its O(1) ? if not then how will i know that what logic is running behind `.contains` or any other function. who will decide time complexity in such cases?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does time complexity changes as we change our programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53919758/does-time-complexity-changes-as-we-change-our-programming-language)

Comment: As stated in that answer: "*The choice of programming language only matters inasmuch as it affects our perception of what we can ignore; but it does not actually change the time complexity.*" Or more specifically, you don't calculate time complexity based on a language.

Comment: so time complexity depends on C language?

Comment: As I said, "*you don't calculate time complexity based on a language*". So the question is moot.

Comment: i understood, but problem is if i write a program in c and same program in java using library functions then how will i determine time complexity of my program?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm).   One of the messages to take from the answers to this other question is that choice of programming language is irrelevant in figuring out the time complexity of an algorithm.